# Can't mock default export in tested file

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, jestjs

I'm working on a Typescript project and I'm trying to add tests for functions that are sorting through MongoDB responses to get meaningful results. I've set up an in-memory mock of the database, now I just need to somehow get the test to use this mock database when running tests on the functions in my file.

I have a file called `mongoClient.ts` that is responsible for this MongoClient object that I need to mock:

```js
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

const client = new MongoClient(`${process.env.MONGO_CONNECT}`);

export default client;
```

The file that I need to test, called `models.ts`, imports `mongoClient` with an ES6 import statement:

```js
import client from '../mongoClient';
```

In my test I have created a `MongoMemoryServer` (mongodb-memory-server), and I have made a class to handle the connection to this MongoMemoryServer:

```js
class dbConnection {
  server;
  connection;
  uri;
  async init() {
    this.server = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
    this.uri = await this.server.getUri();
    this.connection = await new MongoClient(this.uri);
    return this.connection;
  }

  connect() {
    this.connection.connect();
  }

  getClient() {
    return this.connection;
  }

  getUri() {
    return this.uri;
  }

  async stopIt() {
    await this.server.stop();
  }
}
```

I cannot seem to get the models object that I create in the test (with `const models = require('../src/models');`) to mock its import of 'mongoClient'.
I've tried the following:

```js
let mock_db = new dbConnection();
jest.doMock('../src/mongoClient', () => ({
  __es6Module: true,
  default: mock_db.getClient()
}));
```

I tried to use `mock(...)` earlier; that throws this error when I run the test:

```
The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
```

In a `beforeAll(...)` I am able to fill this DB with dummy information so my functions in models will run correctly, but these functions can't see the mock in-memory database because I can't properly mock the mongoClient file that gets imported at the top of my models.ts. I don't want to have to change any code that isn't in a .test file to accomplish this, but I can't get this test environment to point at my mock in-memory database while running these tests. I must be missing something about the implementation of doMock, and I need some help to fix it.

- -**EDIT_1**- - I think this might have something to do with the order in which I'm declaring things. The class `dbConnection` is declared directly under my imports at the top of the test file. Then under that I instantiate the dbConnection class as mockDb and `jest.doMock(...` like in the example shown above. My tested function seems to be trying to use a mocked import that only contains the following:

```js
{"__es6Module":true}
```

The error message I'm getting at this point is `ERROR --- _get__(...).db is not a function`.

The problem with this could be that it's mocking the imported module correctly, but the default export used to mock (`mockDb.getClient()`)  is undefined when it's declared in that doMock statement near the top of the file. I don't know where else to move that doMock, and it breaks if I move it into the top-level beforeAll or into the describe section for these tests or into the test itself.

- -**EDIT_2**- - Changing `__es6Module` to `__esModule`  (because the compiled js file looks for __esModule) makes it so that `undefined` is the contents of the imported class in my code.

The compiled js code has the following at the top:

```js
var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) {
    return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod };
};
const mongoClient_1 = __importDefault(require("../util/mongoClient"));
```

- -**FINAL_EDIT**- - I've figured this out, it was an error on my part in how the order of the Jest tests were being executed. The default export client that I was mocking had not been initialized before the tests were being run. This required that I mock the default import in a `beforeAll(...)` statement inside of each 'describe' block of tests, and in each test I have to instantiate a new models at the start of the test with `const models = require(...);`. I have working tests now, and everything is good in life ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out, it was an error on my part in how the order of the Jest tests were being executed. The default export client that I was mocking had not been initialized before the tests were being run. This required that I mock the default import in a beforeAll(...) statement inside of each 'describe' block of tests, and in each test I have to instantiate a new models at the start of the test with const models = require(...);. I have working tests now